# Unlock The Mystery

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

load-bearer

jailer

poultry

primate

rider

bologna

---

<sub>*Hi guys! Sorry I've been away for so long; hope you enjoy this brief little puzzle.*</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each of these

> clues a word with KEY in it: DONKEY, TURNKEY, TURKEY, MONKEY, JOCKEY, MALARKEY.

(I don't know if there's any more to this puzzle, but it doesn't seem so: the usual methods of extracting from these results don't produce anything useful.)

Comment: Well done! (this wasn't intended to be complex). The title, though, fits in a way.